# Ember.js transition to a route with dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

I have an index page which has an action that creates a record. Then I want to transition to that record, the route has a dynamic segment. I got it working but in a horrible way assigning that = this. I think there is a better way to do this.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        submitHandle: function() {
            var newCard = this.store.createRecord('card', {
                handle: this.get('handle')
            }),

            that = this;

            newCard.save().then(function(savedCard) {
                that.transitionToRoute('card.build', savedCard.get('id'));
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try using that action in your route definition.  I have the feeling transitionToRoute is deprecated and likely wont have the same functionality... then post your update if it works.

Comment: `transitionToRoute` is not going to be deprecated, because it's crucial to many apps' flow.  That being said, your implementation isn't bad... It's just a natural result of working in callback closures. Only thing I would change about that is to pass the `savedCard` directly to the transition, instead of getting its ID, which is unnecessary.  Maybe Also use `replaceRoute` as well, since you don't want the user to click back and see the new form with a persisted model in it.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. After comments and having read this about having actions on routes: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/where-should-i-define-a-save-action/5062/8. I have a much nicer action.

Answer (score 0):

I've been informed it's better to handle actions on the route in most cases following this discussion: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/where-should-i-define-a-save-action/5062/8

And thanks to the comments I came up with this on my index route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        submitHandle: function(handle) {
            var newCard = this.store.createRecord('card', {
                    handle: handle
                });

            newCard.save()

            this.transitionTo('card.build', newCard);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution skip the promise returned by `newCard.save()` what's happen if your save failed ? you fire the transitionTo in any case ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think the `that` is not that uggly, if done properly meaning use a `var that` insteand of `that` var makes the scope of the `that` to a function level, where your `that` makes the scope to a window level (bad) and as `this` is a complex object your `that` will be a pointer to `this`.

Then you can use javascript `bind`to set the "this" context to a function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: that is a var that, just unclear from the formatting.

Comment: `var that` and `that` are both var however in Javascript specification the declaration with `var` and without `var` changes the variable scope, which matters for the grabage collection, variables declared without var are on a `window` level and thus are active during the whole cycle of your application = bad, when `var` take the context (in our case the function) this the var get grabage collected once the function execution is finished.

Comment: I meant the code is var newCard = function (), that; I'm declaring two variables with the keyword var and a , in between.